# android studio swipe views showing different strings stored in array

Tags: string, android-fragments, android-studio, android-viewpager, swipe

I am trying to make an app that shows strings stored in `res` folder. I have tried to implement this with viewpager and fragments. When installed it shows 9 pages with first string in the array in all the 9 pages. Where should I make the change to make it right?

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

   ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    SwipeAdapter swipeAdapter=new SwipeAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager.setAdapter(swipeAdapter);
}
} 

public class PageFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

TextView textView;
String pageData[];
int position;

public PageFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

// Inflate the layout for this fragment
View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_fragment_layout,container,false);

pageData=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.desserts);
textView=((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView));
textView.setText(pageData[position]);
return view;
}
}


public class SwipeAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

public SwipeAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {

    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment=new PageFragment();
    return fragment;
}


@Override

public int getCount() {
    return 9;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    SwipeAdapter swipeAdapter=new  SwipeAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager.setAdapter(swipeAdapter);
}
}     

public class PageFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    TextView textView;
    String pageData[];
    int position;

    public PageFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

     public PageFragment(int position) {
       this.position = position;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_fragment_layout,container,false);

    pageData=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.desserts);
    textView=((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView));
    textView.setText(pageData[position]);
    return view;
    }
    }


    public class SwipeAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

    public SwipeAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {

        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment=new PageFragment(position);
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override

    public int getCount() {
        return 9;
    }
    }
```